# Apple Watch App Fails Submission Invalid Info.plist and Icon

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-watch, xcode-6.2

I am trying to submit my Apple Watch App to Apple.  When validating, it always fails with various info.plist issues.  One of these says:

`The key ‘CFBundleIcons~ipad’ in bundle iPrayed.app/PlugIns/iPrayed WatchKit Extension.appex/iPrayed WatchKit App.app is invalid.`

Also, I get various errors as well about Invalid icon names.  I have searched for these, but I don't see them anywhere.  Also, the CFBundleIcons key in the Watch App never shows on the Info.plist I have in there.  What am I doing wrong?  Attached below are three screenshots, one of the errors, one showing target of watch app, and one of my Image Assets file in Watch App.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a crazy bug on Xcode 6.2 but I found an easy fix (after lots of hard work).

Apparently, Xcode doesn't work well when using same icons for the app and for the watch at the same asset catalog so just separate the icons and that would fix that.

Just a small notice, Pay attention to have a square icon and not to include any transparency on those icons. It would be submit if you do but would reject automatically after few minutes.

Comment: The icons are separated.  I use one asset folder for the iPhone app, and a different one for the Watch App.  They are all stored separately.  The invalid icon names are names of icons that I can't even find anywhere.  Also, that doesn't explain the CFBundleicons~ipad error that it says is in the info.plist but my info.plist doesn't show.

Comment: @user717452 your screenshot shows both apps icon on same asset catalog. You can try and check the json file that describe that asset catalog (that's what is being created from it).

Comment: Whoops, my bad, still had iPhone and iPad sizes checked on the asset catalog for watch...just passed validation.  Wow, that was frustrating.  Thanks!

Comment: Yea, Spent like half day on this issue. I'll file it to Apple now.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what was the app you were submitting, and has it got to In Review yet?

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem and after 3 hours straight I just figured it out.

Open your finder and find the **WATCH** info.PLIST file

Then delete the row that has "CFBundleIcons~ipad"

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Interestingly the CFBundleIcons item did not show on Xcode. Must open it via the finder

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to have two sets of App Icons, let's say, AppIcon and AppIcon-1. AppIcon is part of the main App (in Targets), AppIcon-1 is the WatchKit App (in Targets as well)

AppIcon contains the icons for iPhone, iPad and Watch.
AppIcon-1 contains the icons ONLY for the watch,

[image]
[image]

That fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved:

- Open, in the mode code, Info.plist of "yourapp WatchKit app"
- Delete the following lines:

  ```
  <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
  <dict/><key>CFBundleIcons~ipad</key><dict/>
  ```

My project also the problems you see in the screenshot.[image]
I got around them by identifying these icons in my AppIcon deleting images and uploading them again with the names he wanted Xcode.

Also I don't why there are two < dict/ > in this position.

[Sorry for my english. :-)]