# ERROR ITMS-90363: "Invalid Info.plist key. The key 'CFBundleIcons~ipad' in bundle MyApp.app…

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, app-store-connect, watchkit

I'm getting this error when submitting my app to iTunes Connect via Xcode 6.3:

> ERROR ITMS-90363: "Invalid Info.plist key. The key
>   'CFBundleIcons~ipad' in bundle MyApp.app/PlugIns/MyApp WatchKit
>   Extension.appex/MyApp WatchKit App.app is invalid."

The answers at [Apple Watch App Fails Submission Invalid Info.plist and Icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29416068/apple-watch-app-fails-submission-invalid-info-plist-and-icon) do not solve my problem. My app already has iPad icons in the asset catalog.

Comment: Have you looked at the info.plist for you WatchKit app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apple Watch App Fails Submission Invalid Info.plist and Icon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29416068/apple-watch-app-fails-submission-invalid-info-plist-and-icon)

Comment: Yes: there is no key 'CFBundleIcons~ipad' in the Info.plist for my WatchKit app.

Comment: You should delete the row CFBundleIcons~ipad on AppleWatch info.plist.

Answer (score 2):

I have solve similar issues. **you should delete the row** `CFBundleIcons~ipad` on AppleWatch info.plist.

Hope will helpful to you!

Answer (score 1):

First check 
-**application/AppleWatch Target Select/Build Setting/Packaging/ Info.plist file path**

If you use true path, you right click apple watch plist.file and **Show in Finder**

Edit this file and copy in this path **yourapp WacthKit App/info.plist**